# SQL Server MERGE statement - Move data from one table to another

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In the MERGE statement below, NewTable and OldTable have the same 3 columns: `EmployeeId` and `DivisionId` are `nvarchar(50)` columns and `Unpublished` is a `bit` column.

I need to **move** all the records from OldTable that have Unpublished = 1, into the NewTable. Hence the INSERT (to NewTable) and then DELETE (from OldTable) statements. I have to use MERGE (as a part of the migration rules).

The INSERT part works fine, but the DELETE part is giving me an error saying "An action of type 'DELETE' is not allowed in the 'WHEN NOT MATCHED' clause of a MERGE statement."

How should the DELETE clause be written in this case?

```
MERGE NewTable as target
USING OldTable as source
on target.EmployeeId = source.EmployeeId
WHEN NOT MATCHED AND source.Unpublished = 1
THEN INSERT (EmployeeId,DivisionId,Unpublished)
VALUES (source.EmployeeId, DivisionId, source.Unpublished)
WHEN NOT MATCHED AND source.Unpublished = 1
THEN DELETE;
```

Comment: `WHEN NOT MATCHED` when not followed by `BY SOURCE` or `BY TARGET` is therefore default to `BY TARGET`, and it doesn't make sense to `DELETE` rows that don't exist.

Comment: Please consider separate delete / insert actions instead of `MERGE`. Obligatory: https://sqlblog.org/merge

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Thanks but like I said, I have to use MERGE as a part of the migration rules.

Comment: Whoever wrote or enforces those migration rules, send them the link. It is foolish IMHO, especially for such a simple case. They are probably under the misconception that MERGE is more efficient, or is isolated without HOLDLOCK, or who knows what else.

Comment: I doubt you "have" to, @bigShaq . More likely you are being "told to", and the person telling you doesn't "know better"; if they did, they would have at least told you to have a `HOLDLOCK` hint.

Comment: @Larnu - I added `WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE` before the `DELETE`. I get this error "The identifier 'source.Unpublished' cannot be bound. Only target columns and columns in the clause scope are allowed in the 'WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE' clause of a MERGE statement."

Answer (score 3):

Let's begin by using some formatting that might convince an existing status quo to change:

### The people in the comments are veterans. The `MERGE` statement is seducing in its syntax, but not implemented well and full of dangers. Avoid it.

Now that we got this out of the way, the next thing is to understand what exactly you want to delete. I noticed this in your question:

> and then DELETE (from OldTable) statements

The merge statements can perform all of (insert,update,delete) on a single table, the one aliased after the `merge`, in your case, `NewTable`. But, you cannot delete from another table (OldTable) within the same merge. What you can do is use an `output` clause to keep track of which rows were `inserted` in NewTable so that you can *then* run a delete on OldTable.